# Determine the appropriate design pattern in Java/Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, design-patterns, rule-engine

We have a method which contains a complex business logic to evaluate a lot of conditions and by the end this method should return an object of type `Rule`.

The method is implemented using a lot of `if else` with nested `if else` as well. **`The execution order is VERY IMPORTANT`** in our situation.

We want to refactor this method using a **design pattern**. I saw a lot of people on stackoverflow talking about **`Chain of Responsibility`**, **`Command`**, **`Factory`** and **`State Pattern`** but I'm not sure about the right pattern for this use case.

Comment: I don't believe you  have presented enough information for us to be able to help you. The question seems way too broad to be suitable for Stack Overflow, which is intended to answer narrowly focused questions.

Comment: To better understand  how to use Stack Overflow, I suggest the following resources, with links on those pages: The [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Are you trying to refactor so that each condition has its own class?

Comment: @aled useless comment, I already know them and I've used them in other situations but in this case I can't find the best one, thanks anyway :)

Comment: @DavidOsborne yes exactly, as I said the order of the execution matter in my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked at doing something similar recently. I found the solution fell between the [Visitor](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/visitor) and [Chain of Responsibility](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/chain-of-responsibility) patterns. Neither provided a natural fit.

I was able to compose a list of the objects that had to be given a chance to perform some business logic and return the final result. Each had a unique set of dependencies. I used an IoC container to resolve these objects using a common interface. I was able to order these by using a property that represented the sequence and sorting the list by this.

The problem I had was that each object needed different runtime data. The Visitor and Chain of Responsibility patterns typically use a consistent method signature. I found I needed a 'context' object parameter to cover all the potential properties each logic object might need. This is when I knew it really the correct approach as many objects were being passed data they weren't interested in.

Due to time constraints, I reverted to something similar to the [Template Method](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/template-method) pattern, but was just a [Transaction Script](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/transactionScript.html) really, where the method called each object following a defined sequence. Objects were resolved via IoC and had interfaces for some abstraction that supported automated testing. This was ok, but became tricky with tests as it required more mocking than it should.

Ultimately, I think something like this doesn't have a neat, 'classic' design pattern that solves it. I think you're looking to refactor your business logic into individual classes and then call them via an iterator or pipeline? if you redefine your question highlighting that design problem rather than trying to find a pattern that fits, you might get a better answer.